# Identifying the attributes of a Selenium element?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to identify the attributes of a Selenium web element. Basically I need to go to a product page, have the user identify an input field, then grab some attributes (Like first name, last name, etc) so I can identify the same element on another product page (So I can't use Xpath since they are unique IDs and that wouldn't work on another product page on the same site).

This is what I have so far, but when I click the "first name" field, it's returning id = 'formPreviewArea' does that mean it's only recognizing the form itself? Can anyone help me figure out how to get some identifying information about the field when I click it?

Ideally I want to be able to click the "first name" field for example and return "first name" but I know not every input element is going to have the same attributes. So how can I allow the user to click the input field and return something that would allow me to find that same element on for example a check-out page for another product on a web store?

```py
from selenium import webdriver #For automation
from pynput.mouse import Listener #For OnMouseClick
global driver

def OpenBrowser(url):
    global driver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\David\Desktop\Python\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    return

def InputClicked(*args):
    active_element = driver.switch_to.active_element
    attrs = driver.execute_script('var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;', active_element)
    print(attrs)

OpenBrowser('https://www.jotform.com/form-templates/choir-signup-form')

with Listener(on_click=InputClicked) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

This is what the code is returning right now.

```py
{'data': '/form-templates/preview/20825060529450/classic&nofs', 'id': 'formPreviewArea', 'style': 'height: 571px;', 'type': 'text/html', 'width': '100%'}
```

Comment: In general, you can't do what you are attempting to do. There's nothing that guarantees that the ID that identifies the element that is the first name field on one site will work for any other site. For example, the Choir Signup Form's First Name field has an ID of "first_3". That's not likely to work anywhere else except by complete coincidence.

Comment: The thing is, I don't need it to be accurately identifying info. The use case for this is I need to allow someone to identify the input fields of a product page on a web store, so that when an out-of-stock item is in-stock, I can have the program purchase the item and fill out the forms automatically.

There are tons of programs called sneaker bots that do this already, I just can't seem to figure out how to auto-complete a form when the exact page that I will be accessing is initially unavailable since the product is sold out.

Or maybe I CAN use an xpath here?